# Basic Logs, simplifying

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

So basically the question goes: $\log_{14} 2 = a$, $\log_{14} 3 = b$, solve for $\log_7 24$. I have attached my work so far and the answer is ${3a+b}\over{1-a}$... I just got stuck at the end. Thanks[image]

Comment: I can't really read your handwriting, but here's a hint $24=2^3.3$.

Comment: I got $\frac{3 \log(2)+\log(3)}{\log(7)}$ if you want simplest form.

Comment: @JulianRachman, you should write up your work and post it as an answer.

Comment: @JulianRachman  it wants the answer in terms of a and b, because the answer is {3a+b}\over{1-a} i just can't figure out to get it

Comment: OK everyone. I'll will do that. :) give me a momento por favor.

Comment: Nevemind. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @JulianRachman, I'm sorry, just saw the comments!

Answer (score 2):

Using: $log_x y={\log_m y\over{\log_m x}}$, $\log_x y^c=c\log_x y$ and $\log_x a+\log_x b=\log_x ab$ we get

$\log_{7} 24 = 3\log_7{2}+\log_7{3}={3\log_{14}2\over{\log_{14}7}}+{\log_{14}3\over{\log_{14}7}}={{3\log_{14}2+\log_{14}3}\over{\log_{14}7 }}$

$$={{3\log_{14}2+\log_{14}3}\over{\log_{14}7 +\log_{14}2-\log_{14}2}}$$
$$={{3\log_{14}2+\log_{14}3}\over{\log_{14}14-\log_{14}2}}={{3a+b}\over{1-a}}$$

Comment: wow thanks, i didn't even think of that rule. i am very pleased that i actually understand this now

Comment: You are welcome! Take a look at this, will definitely help you in that case: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Logarithmic_identities

Comment: quick question, why did you subtract log 2 base 14 on the bottom of the fraction in the 3rd to last step?

Comment: I did not just subtract it - I added and subtracted it, hence net effect is 0! $\log_{14}7 = {\log_{14}7 +\log_{14}2-\log_{14}2}$ so that we get $ \log_{14}7 +\log_{14}2=\log_{14}7.2=\log_{14}14$ which is 1, and we know what $\log_{14}2$ is!

Answer (score 1):

In your approach you tackle the problem using the definition: $\log_x y = z \iff y=x^z.$ You just need to solve $\log_7 2$, and you'd be done. Jump to the second-to-last line for that.

---

We know that $\log_{14} 2 = a$ means $2=14^a$, and $\log_{14} 3 = b$ means $3=14^b$.

We'd like to solve for $\log_{7} 24 = x.$ In other words, $24=7^x$.

Now notice that $2\cdot 2\cdot 2 \cdot 3= 24$.

Substituting what we know from our first line above, we have:

$$14^a 14^a 14^a 14^b = 14^{3a+b} = (2\cdot 7)^{3a+b} = \color{green}{2^{3a+b} 7^{3a+b} = 7^x}.$$

Taking $\log_7$ of both sides of the equation in green, we have 
$$(3a+b)\log_7 2 +(3a+b) = x.$$

So, $$(3a+b)(\log_7 2 + 1) = x.$$

But what is $\log_7 2$? Well, notice that $2=14^a=2^a7^a$, which is equivalent to $2^{1-a}=7^a$. So $(1-a)\log_7 2 = a$. Therefore $\log_7 2 = \dfrac{a}{1-a}$.

So, $$(3a+b)\left(\frac{a}{1-a} + 1\right) = x.$$